# How to implement svg pattern via d3js?

Tags: svg, d3.js

I would like to add a pattern to some of my svg map's polygons via d3js, the disputed areas. I already add thesr geographic shapes well, I also saw svg patterns are possible in native svg :

```html
<svg width="120" height="120" viewBox="0 0 120 120" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" version="1.1" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink">
    <defs>
        <pattern id="Triangle" width="10" height="10" patternUnits="userSpaceOnUse">
            <path fill="black"d="M5,0 10,10 0,10 Z" />
        </pattern>
    </defs>
    <circle cx="60" cy="60" r="50" fill="url(#Triangle)" />
</svg>
```

**But how to add hash patterns to my d3js geographic shapes ?**

Answer (score 13, accepted):

It's straight forward when we know the right xml syntax that you just provided :)

#### D3js pattern snippet

```js
// SVG injection:
var svg = d3.select("#hook").append("svg").attr("id", "d3svg")
    .attr("width", 120)
    .attr("height", 120);
//Pattern injection
var defs = svg.append("defs")
var pattern = defs.append("pattern")
  .attr({ id:"hash4_4", width:"8", height:"8", patternUnits:"userSpaceOnUse", patternTransform:"rotate(-45)"})
 .append("rect")
  .attr({ width:"4", height:"8", transform:"translate(0,0)", fill:"#88AAEE" });

//Shape design
svg.append("g").attr("id","shape")
    .append("circle")
.attr({cx:"60",cy:"60",r:"50", fill:"url(#hash4_4)" })
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/3.4.11/d3.min.js"></script>
<div id="hook"></div>
```

#### Use

To use on your svg groups or elements:

```
g.attr("fill", "url(#hash4_4)" )
```

#### Concept

Going backward, any diagonal strip is a rotated vertical hash. The basic pattern of a vertical hash is a square area, of which a part is a vertical line taking more or less of the horizontal width, by example 4px colored out of 8px width for the square. Repeat this pattern, rotate, and you have it.

#### Pattern's colors

Changing the pattern's fill will affect the elements using this pattern.

#### Other patterns

Similarly, you can include more complex svg pattern by designing paths within a square. By example via:

```
pattern.append("path").attr("d", "M5,0 10,10 0,10 Z") 
// small triangle but can be pushed further !
```

For a gist on svg path, check [svg path & commnands](http://jsfiddle.net/jwrmwxzt/7/).

**[Demo fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/epe083vk/4/)**

Comment: Nice! Just what I was looking for. Thanks!